# Android: EditText text alignment on Fragment not working (API 16)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have some `EditText` and `TextView` inside a `Fragment`. On the XML layout of the fragment I have added the following in EditText and TextView:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Then I have tested the app in the emulator, on virtual device with `API 25`, and all seems to work fine, the fragment is displayed as it looks in the design window, with the text centered in both the EditText and the TextView.

However, I have launched the app in my own phone `Android 4.1.2 API 16` and also in another virtual device that I have also created with `API 16` and now none of the 'EditText' or 'TextView' are respecting the `textAlignment` property, **the text is just displayed aligned to the left side.**

Any help?, I am looking around but I cannot find anything related to API 16 and problems like that with alignments.

Comment: Instead of use *Gravity* may be work for all.

Comment: is that ok? I mean, Gravity might center the whole widget...while for example, in `EditText` I want the text centered `inside` the editText

Comment: @eddie show your xml please

Comment: @eddie Check my answer. *android:gravity* will center your text only not whole *widget*.

Comment: @jaydroider im on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that with below. As i mentioned in comment also.

```
         <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_bio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Bio DAte aaaaaaaa"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="3"
                tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
```

Comment: yes man, now it works, I will read a bit more about it because i do not understand very well yet about `gravity` and `textAlignment`, but still THANKS!!, I accept your answer when I can since yours was the first comment

Comment: @eddie Welcome :).

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

> Place the object in the center of its container in both the vertical
>   and horizontal axis, not changing its size.

Comment: thanks, I give it a try, but, for example, in `EditText`, I want the text centered inside the widget, not sure if `gravity` fulfills this, but still worth it to try

Answer (score 1):

Check official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTextAlignment(int)).

`android:textAlignment="center"` or its setter were introduced in API 17. So it won't work on earlier devices i.e. API 16.

Instead use `android:gravity` which should provide the same functionality both in `EditText` and `TextView`.